# Optimality conditions for quadratic programs

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Here is the problem I am currently working on:

[image]

I am really struggling with 4b and these more general quadratic programs. I've tried applying Wolfe's method for Quadratic Programs, but that isn't working for me. Any tips on how to find optimality conditions for these more general kinds of Quadratic programs? Thanks so much!

Comment: What happened when you tried to write down the KKT conditions?

Comment: Link for comment by @littleO https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions